# Unknown error while generating a push notification certificate

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Have anyone experienced this error, from the Apple's developer console?

[image: Error]

The strange thing is that according to the next screen, everything has been perfect:

[image]

At last, my push notification does not work, and I wonder If the problem comes from this "error".

**EDIT :**
It comes just after uploading the `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest`file generated by the Keychain Access application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem !

I has this error message on Google Chrome (v19.0.1084.56), and when I tried on Safari everything worked perfectly.

I didn't try on other web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Section Configure your app in iOS Provisioning portal in http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/ mentions clear steps to generate the push notifications enabled provisioning certificate.

Comment: I do know how to create a push certificate... That does not answer my question.

Comment: I am having the same issue...Not sure why